# Remove specific hardware request from Android app

Tags: android, android-camera, android-manifest

In my app I use Camera object to turn flashlight on. However, I do check if there's flashlight, and if there isn't, I don't use make any calls to Camera object. However, there's still an automatic requirement added to manifest - android.hardware.camera.

How can I remove it? I can guarantee that there will be no calls to Camera if there's no camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)** along with `<uses-permission>` attribute in the Manifest for features that are used in the app but not extremely required.

For e.g here,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

By explicitly specifying the **[`android:required`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#required)** attribute as `false`, the app can work in devices with no Camera

From the documentation page

> If a feature is explicitly declared as not being required, Google Play
>   does not add the feature to the list of required features. For that
>   reason, an explicitly declared non-required feature is never
>   considered when filtering the application. Even if the device does not
>   provide the declared feature, Google Play will still consider the
>   application compatible with the device and will show it to the user,
>   unless other filtering rules apply.

Like Google Play filters app, if a hardware feature is provided with explicitly declared as not required, the app can work in devices with no Camera support